# Add Trace Logs to an existing application

Tags: c#, .net, logging

My team has inherited a new application from this other team. The application is huge and does not have any logging. We would really want to have some level of logging,trace logging to begin with, at the start and end of each method.
Wanted to check if there is any application/ product/ dll available which can add logs to an existing .net application with minimal changes.
We have thousands of methods and would prefer not to add attributes/ lines of code to each of these methods.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks, 
Kunal

Comment: You should look in to [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) and [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) are two popular libraries to do it.

Comment: [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is a nice option as well. Ours is setup to log all public method calls. Should work with minimal setup.